# How to display specific database entries into a textbox on a WinForm application

Tags: c#, sql-server, windows, winforms, forms

UPDATE:
Thanks everyone, the code was not the issue, although the information regarding SQL injection was useful, my issue was that I was using an older version of my database which did not have the corresponding product ID so it was instead using the first product that it could find. Feel very stupid now but thanks for the suggestions.

I currently have the following code :

```
SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=(LocalDB)\v11.0 AttachDbFilename=C:\Users\h8005267\Desktop\Practical Project\Build\System4\System\StockControl.mdf;Integrated Security=True;Connect Timeout=30");
connection.Open();
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM Product WHERE ProductID='" + textBox3.Text + "'", connection); 
SqlDataReader re = cmd.ExecuteReader();

if (re.Read())
{
  textBox4.Text = re["ProductTitle"].ToString(); // only fills using first product in table
  textBox5.Text = re["ProductPublisherArtist"].ToString();
  comboBox1.Text = re["ProductType"].ToString();
  textBox6.Text = re["Price"].ToString();
}
else
{
  MessageBox.Show("Please enter a valid item barcode");
}
re.Close();
connection.Close();
```

The issue I am currently having is although the text boxes display the information on button click, the information displayed is only the first row of data in the database, NOT the row corresponding to the textbox3 in the sql statement

Comment: I had 2 points of intrest: 1 is mentioned in comment above, the other is that I hope you don't really use those naming methods for controls either, that this is purely for demo purposes.

Comment: Ah, little Bobby Tables, how we love you.

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow! There's no need to include tags in your titles. See http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/19190 for the general discussion.

Comment: Do you have several items in your database with the same ProductID. From your query, do you get an item with a productid other than the one you requested?

Comment: yes its just for demo purposes. I am fairly new at this and just trying to understand as I go.Also no item in the database has the same product ID, i got the first item in the database regardless of the id entered

Answer (score 4):

Try this instead. Avoid building SQL statement dynamically the way you are doing it. You are opening your database to risks of SQL Injection. Used parameters insead.

```
using (var connection = new SqlConnection("connection string"))
{
    connection.Open();
    using (var cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM Product WHERE ProductID=@MYVALUE", connection))
    {
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@MYVALUE", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = textBox3.Text;
        SqlDataReader re = cmd.ExecuteReader();

        if (re.Read())
        {
            textBox4.Text = re["ProductTitle"].ToString(); // only fills using first product in table
            textBox5.Text = re["ProductPublisherArtist"].ToString();
            comboBox1.Text = re["ProductType"].ToString();
            textBox6.Text = re["Price"].ToString();
        }
        else
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Please enter a valid item barcode");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks for this response, When i run the code I still get the same issue, when I input the product ID the information written to the textbox is still the first line in the database regardless of what product ID I enter

Comment: Could it be because your query is returning more than one result? Is your ProductID column a primary key?

Comment: thanks again for responding, yes the product ID is my primary key for the product table. each product ID is unique for each product

Comment: Do you have any relationships on your table? you could be missing joins in your query.

Comment: yes i have relationships connected, the product table is connected to another table via the productID

Comment: Thanks everyone, I have the problem resolved it was an issue on my part regarding the database version I was using not the code. Thanks for the help and thank you for explaining my issues regarding SQL attacks.

Comment: @user2274228: Please add an answer that solves your problem, or update your question with the solution at the bottom, so others with the same error can find a solution to their problems.

Answer (score 2):

put a breakpoint on that line

```
SqlDataReader re = cmd.ExecuteReader();
```

and enter the following into textBox3

```
'; DROP TABLE Product; SELECT '
```

the ' are to be entered in your textbox. now execute your method and carefully read the resulting sql command... welcome to sql injection ;)

@M Patel: thx for your comment and you are perfectly right

The result would be the following SQL

```
SELECT * FROM Product WHERE ProductID=''; DROP TABLE Product; SELECT ''
```

And this would allow a malicious user to destroy your database.

To prevent that you should work with prepared Statements like M Patel suggested in his answer

Comment: This doesn't answer the question.

Comment: that's true - feel free to downvote my answer for that. But pointing out the riskiness of the code seemed worth it

Comment: The riskiness is already pointed out by both of the other answers. If you would expand your answer to include a segment on parameterized queries, you would have earned an upvote instead.

Comment: well the other answers merely mentioned the risk of sql injection and didn't explaint it so that a novice programmer sees the problem immediatly. btw the other answeres were not there when i posted mine.

And concerning the segment on parameterized queries: i think the other answers cover that quite well

Comment: In that case a simple *comment* would suffice. "Please see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection for the problems with SQL injection".

Comment: Although this didn't answer my question it has helped me understand where my code was risky, I am purely building this as a demo however this will help me in the future.

Answer (score 2):

you have SQL Injection problem with `'" + textBox3.Text + "'"`

and you don't have to name your controls like that, you have to use a meaningful names

you can use this code

```
using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=(LocalDB)\v11.0 AttachDbFilename=C:\Users\h8005267\Desktop\Practical Project\Build\System4\System\StockControl.mdf;Integrated Security=True;Connect Timeout=30"))
{
    connection.Open();
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM Product WHERE ProductID=@ProductID", connection);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ProductID", textBox3.Text);
    SqlDataReader re = cmd.ExecuteReader();
    if (re.Read())
    {
        textBox4.Text = re.GetString(re.GetOrdinal("ProductTitle")); // only fills using first product in table
        textBox5.Text = re.GetString(re.GetOrdinal("ProductPublisherArtist"));
        comboBox1.Text = re.GetString(re.GetOrdinal("ProductType"));
        textBox6.Text = re.GetString(re.GetOrdinal("Price"));
    }
    else
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Please enter a valid item barcode");
    }
    re.Close();
}
```