# How do I get data from SQL Server to text boxes in Visual Studio

Tags: c#, sql-server

I am working in Visual Studio using C#. I need to get data from different database tables in SQL Server into text boxes on a Visual Studio form. The database tables have several rows and columns. The values are character and real values. I am using the code below. I don’t get the real values to text boxes. I get no errors and empty text boxes. I can get the character values. Can anyone please help? Thanks.

```
namespace WindowsFormsApplication1
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

         SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection("DataSource=192.146.1,5,1433;Network Library=DBMSSOCN;Initial Catalog=Estimator;User ID=id;Password=password;Trusted_Connection=True");

            con.Open();

            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("select * from Table1", con);
            SqlDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();

            while (dr.Read())
            {
                textBox1.Text = dr.GetString(1);
                textBox2.Text = dr.GetString(2);
                textBox2.Text = dr.GetString(3);
            }

            con.Close();    

        }

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: When you debug the code, does it enter the while loop?

Comment: Yes, it enters the while loop, thanks.

Comment: Dont show your public ip address on the www. Please edit you question and change it to something else. Like xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx

Answer (score 1):

Not sure why yours is not working but this similar post

[How to display specific database entries into a textbox on a WinForm application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15970472/how-to-display-specific-database-entries-into-a-textbox-on-a-winform-application)

has several working examples.

You do have some odd stuff like datasource is spelled wrong and there are not enough digits in your IP address.

Comment: I don't get anything. I get blank text boxes.

Comment: I have everything correct in my code. I did not type datasource and IP address correctly in this page.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if `SqlDataReader.GetString()` will implicitly accept `real` data types.

But, nonetheless, I'd modify your `while` like this:

```
while (dr.Read())
        {
            var c1 = dr.Item[0];
            var c2 = dr.Item[1];
            var c3 = dr.Item[2];
            textBox1.Text = dr.GetString(1);
            textBox2.Text = dr.GetString(2);
            textBox2.Text = dr.GetString(3);
        }
```

This way you can see if there's anything actually coming out of you `SqlDataReader`. I'd only do this to help with the debugging process.